# Getting iput from the user: Haskell

Tags: haskell

This is haskell. The program is alright. I need to do one more thing but I am unable to. In my code the input lets say 17 does not come from the user I initialized it. I have been unable to input the number from the user. That is my specific query

**Question is**
Given a list of numbers and a number k, return whether any two numbers from the list add up to k. For example, given [10, 15, 3, 7] and k of 17, return true since 10 + 7 is 17.

**Here is the code. I tried something like this**

```
toList :: String -> [Integer]
toList input = read ("[" ++ input ++ "]")



check :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Bool 
check k (x:xs) = if ((k-x) `elem` xs) 
         then True
         else (check k xs)
check k x = False 

main = do
 let k = input <- getLine
 putStrLn "Enter a list of numbers (separated by comma):"
 input <- getLine
 print $  (check k  (toList input))
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate check the edited code now

Comment: `let k = input <- getLine` is sintactically wrong. just `k <- getLine`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `getLine` as many times you want.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Enter a number:"
  k <- read <$> getLine 
  putStrLn "Enter a list of numbers (separated by comma):"
  input <- toList <$> getLine
  print $ check k input
```

Comment: There is some kind of parse error. That is what I have been getting. parse error on input `='

Comment: @Code365 when compiling or executing?